# understanding mysql explain

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, optimization

So, I've never understood the explain of MySQL. I understand the gross concepts that you should have at least one entry in the `possible_keys` column for it to use an index, and that simple queries are better. But what is the difference between ref and eq_ref? What is the best way to be optimizing queries.

For example, this is my latest query that I'm trying to figure out why it takes forever (generated from `django` models) :

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type   | possible_keys                                             | key                             | key_len | ref                                  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T6                  | ref    | yourock_achiever_achievement_id,yourock_achiever_alias_id | yourock_achiever_alias_id       | 4       | const                                |  244 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T5                  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                   | PRIMARY                         | 4       | paul.T6.achievement_id               |    1 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T4                  | ref    | yourock_achiever_achievement_id,yourock_achiever_alias_id | yourock_achiever_achievement_id | 4       | paul.T6.achievement_id               |  298 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | yourock_alias       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                   | PRIMARY                         | 4       | paul.T4.alias_id                     |    1 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | yourock_achiever    | ref    | yourock_achiever_achievement_id,yourock_achiever_alias_id | yourock_achiever_alias_id       | 4       | paul.T4.alias_id                     |  152 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | yourock_achievement | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                   | PRIMARY                         | 4       | paul.yourock_achiever.achievement_id |    1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I had hoped to learn enough about mysql explain that the query wouldn't be needed. Alas, it seems that you can't get enough information from the explain statement and you need the raw SQL. Query :

```
SELECT  `yourock_achievement`.`id`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`modified`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`created`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`string_id`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`owner_id`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`name`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`description`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`owner_points`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`url`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`remote_image`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`image`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`parent_achievement_id`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`slug`,
        `yourock_achievement`.`true_points`
FROM    `yourock_achievement`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_achiever`
ON       `yourock_achievement`.`id` = `yourock_achiever`.`achievement_id`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_alias`
ON      `yourock_achiever`.`alias_id` = `yourock_alias`.`id`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_achiever` T4
ON      `yourock_alias`.`id` = T4.`alias_id`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_achievement` T5
ON      T4.`achievement_id` = T5.`id`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_achiever` T6
ON      T5.`id` = T6.`achievement_id`
WHERE
        T6.`alias_id` = 6
ORDER BY
        `yourock_achievement`.`modified` DESC
```

Comment: Not quite to the point, but I'd recommend this for mysql performance monitoring and tuning: http://www.jetprofiler.com/

Comment: Could you please post the query itself?

Comment: Could you please calculate `COUNT(*)` of rows returned, as in my post?

Comment: I tried running that query for 10 minutes, no result. I can count the entries in the various tables if you want.

Comment: Ok, it finished in 12 mins. 349285347 rows... yeah, I guess that answers the question :( There should be a group by somewhere, no idea how django threw it out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Paul:

> **eq_ref**
>
> One row is read from this table for each combination of rows from the previous tables. **Other than the system and const types, this is the best possible join type.** It is used when all parts of an index are used by the join and the index is a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index.
>
> eq_ref can be used for indexed columns that are compared using the = operator. The comparison value can be a constant or an expression that uses columns from tables that are read before this table. In the following examples, MySQL can use an eq_ref join to process ref_table:

```
SELECT * FROM ref_table,other_table
WHERE ref_table.key_column=other_table.column;

SELECT * FROM ref_table,other_table
WHERE ref_table.key_column_part1=other_table.column
AND ref_table.key_column_part2=1;
```

> **ref**
>
> All rows with matching index values are read from this table for each combination of rows from the previous tables. **ref is used if the join uses only a leftmost prefix of the key or if the key is not a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index (in other words, if the join cannot select a single row based on the key value)**. If the key that is used matches only a few rows, this is a good join type.
>
> ref can be used for indexed columns that are compared using the = or <=> operator. In the following examples, MySQL can use a ref join to process ref_table:

```
SELECT * FROM ref_table WHERE key_column=expr;

SELECT * FROM ref_table,other_table
WHERE ref_table.key_column=other_table.column;

SELECT * FROM ref_table,other_table
WHERE ref_table.key_column_part1=other_table.column
AND ref_table.key_column_part2=1;
```

These are copied verbatim from the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

If you could post your query that is taking *forever*, I could help pinpoint what is slowing it down. Also, please specify what your definition of *forever* is. Also, if you could provide your "SHOW CREATE TABLE xxx;" statements for these tables, I could help in optimizing your query as much as possible.

What jumps out at me immediately as a possible point of improvement is the "Using temporary; Using filesort;". This means that a temporary table was created to satisfy the query (not necessarily a bad thing), and that the GROUP BY/ORDER BY you designated could not be retrieved from an index, thus resulting in a *filesort*.

Answer (score 4):

You query seems to process `(244 * 298 * 152) = 11,052,224` records, which according to `Using temporary; Using filesort` need to be sorted.

This can take long.

If you post your query here, we probably will be able to optimize it somehow.

**Update:**

You query indeed does a number of nested loops and seems to yield lots of values which need to be sorted then.

Could you please run the following query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    `yourock_achievement`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_achiever`
ON       `yourock_achievement`.`id` = `yourock_achiever`.`achievement_id`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_alias`
ON      `yourock_achiever`.`alias_id` = `yourock_alias`.`id`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_achiever` T4
ON      `yourock_alias`.`id` = T4.`alias_id`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_achievement` T5
ON      T4.`achievement_id` = T5.`id`
INNER JOIN
        `yourock_achiever` T6
ON      T5.`id` = T6.`achievement_id`
WHERE
        T6.`alias_id` = 6
```

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. Those numbers do not mean the query returns that many records. In fact it designates that MySQL has to read this many rows to determine which to return.

Comment: @hobodave: since we see no additional `Using where` here, it will be safe to assume that all these rows will be in fact returned (espesially lacking other information on the query).

Comment: That cannot be assumed. A simple "LIMIT 1", among other things, disproves your assumption.

Comment: @hobodave: you're right in that sense they don't necessarily need to be returned to the client, but they still need to be returned to the sorter / distinctifier (which is there according to `Using filesort`).

Comment: @hobodave: I'll better word it as "to process" to avoid confusion.