# Why does longer query perform faster than short one using WHERE IN clause?

Tags: mysql, where-in

I'm trying to figure this out why the longer query runs faster than the short one. Could it be due to some indexes?

This query takes around half a second.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT `positions`.`id`, 
               `positions`.`keyword_id`, 
               `positions`.`position`, 
               @rank := IF(@group = keyword_id, @rank + 1, 1) AS 
               rank_08b5648409889380fe88d86c30ff4c8d, 
               @group := keyword_id                           AS 
                      group_08b5648409889380fe88d86c30ff4c8d 
        FROM   (SELECT @rank := 0, 
                       @group := 0) AS vars, 
               positions 
        ORDER  BY `keyword_id` ASC, 
                  `created_at` DESC) AS positionsA 
       LEFT JOIN `positions` 
              ON `positionsa`.`id` = `positions`.`id` 
WHERE  `rank_08b5648409889380fe88d86c30ff4c8d` <= '2' 
       AND `positions`.`keyword_id` IN ( '1', '2', '3', ..., '1879', '1880' )
```

While this exact same query, with many less items in the `IN` statement takes around 2 seconds:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT `positions`.`id`, 
               `positions`.`keyword_id`, 
               `positions`.`position`, 
               @rank := IF(@group = keyword_id, @rank + 1, 1) AS 
               rank_08b5648409889380fe88d86c30ff4c8d, 
               @group := keyword_id                           AS 
                      group_08b5648409889380fe88d86c30ff4c8d 
        FROM   (SELECT @rank := 0, 
                       @group := 0) AS vars, 
               positions 
        ORDER  BY `keyword_id` ASC, 
                  `created_at` DESC) AS positionsA 
       LEFT JOIN `positions` 
              ON `positionsa`.`id` = `positions`.`id` 
WHERE  `rank_08b5648409889380fe88d86c30ff4c8d` <= '2' 
       AND `positions`.`keyword_id` IN ( '1', '2', '3', ..., '164', '165' )
```

All performance tests are done in PHPmyAdmin.

Here is what explain is returning:

Faster, longer query:

[image]

Slower, shorter query:

[image]

`show create table positions` returns this:

```
CREATE TABLE `positions` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
 UNIQUE KEY `keyword_id_created_at_index` (`keyword_id`,`created_at`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=467923 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And these are the indexes on that table:

[image]

Comment: Run explain on both queries and copy the outputs into the question. Without that, we can only guess.

Comment: @Shadow my guess, fractional share on GoDaddy phpmyadmin. And the other guys were "doing stuff"

Comment: @Shadow, ok I added explain screenshots of each.

Comment: @Drew, it's running on my local, so nothing related to GoDaddy.

Comment: and what is the output of  `show create table positions` as in See **Section2** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465)

Comment: @Shadow if interested check out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1159772) I have to scoot

Comment: Your indexes do not seem to be that good. Can you pls provide the list of indexs with the fields they cover for all affected tables?

Comment: @Drew, I added the result of `show create table positions`.

Comment: @Shadow, I also added the indexes on that table.

Comment: Looks like if I delete the `keyword_id_created_at_index` then both queries start performing similarly, at around 0.5 seconds.  I'm confused why the query affected the short query in a negative way though.  I would have thought the index would have helped since I was using both keyword_id and created_at in the query.