# Improving SELECT performance in two unioned (UNION ALL) huge tables

Tags: mysql, union

I have two huge tables and need the following query be to executed. Both table `authors_1` (~20M rows) and `authors_2` (~120M rows) have the same structure. I've done my researches and came up with the following query and table structures. It still takes a long time (usually between 10 to 20 seconds) for the query.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT `fname`, `lname` 
FROM (
    SELECT `fname`, `lname` 
    FROM `authors_1` 
    WHERE 1 AND `lname` LIKE 'AR%' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT `fname`, `lname` 
    FROM `authors_2` 
    WHERE 1 AND `lname` LIKE 'AR%') `a` 
GROUP BY CONCAT(`fname`, `lname`) 
ORDER BY `lname` 
LIMIT 0, 999;
```

and this is the structure, which is similar for both tables (The `FT` indexes are for other queries).

```
CREATE TABLE `scipers_authors` (
 `a_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `linker` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `fname` tinytext COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL, /*Should this be tinytext because of FT index or I can use VARCHAR(255) while having FT index?*/
 `lname` tinytext COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL, /*Same for this one*/
 PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `linker` (`linker`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `lname_4` (`lname`(4)) USING BTREE,
 KEY `name` (`lname`(128),`fname`(128)) USING BTREE,
 FULLTEXT KEY `fname` (`fname`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `lname` (`lname`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;
```

This is the `EXPLAIN` output for the example query shown above (I don't know how to make it beautiful [like others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157970/understanding-mysql-explain), I'm using PMA):

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 476968  Using temporary; Using filesort 
2   DERIVED authors_1   range   lname_4,name,lname  name    386     184800  Using where 
3   UNION   authors_2   range   lname_4,name,lname  name    386     292168  Using where 
    UNION RESULT    <union2,3>  ALL                     Using temporary
```

Any suggestion for improving this query/structure?

Comment: I don't think you need the `lname_4` index, since it's a prefix of the `name` index. Notice that the `name` index gets used instead. How many rows satisfy the `LIKE` criteria?

Comment: change **GROUP BY CONCAT(`fname`, `lname`)** to **GROUP BY `fname`, `lname`** then mysql can use a index ( if there is one)

Comment: +1 for stating `I've done my researches and came up....` Carrying out research *before* asking on SO is always a good sign `:-)`. And also showing an `EXPLAIN`, too.

Comment: @Barmar, for the given query it's around 320K rows. I thought `lname_4` could help as it only has the first 4 letters indexed.

Comment: A B-tree index can be used to optimize any prefix of the index. So another index for the prefix is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `GROUP BY CONCAT(fname, lname)` to `GROUP BY fname, lname`. Doing all those concatenations is extra work that's unnecessary.

The only semantic difference between these is if there are two people whose first and last names are different, but they're the same when concatenated, e.g. Freda Smith and Fred Asmith. Such combinations are probably unlikely, and I doubt you really wanted them to be combined into a single result in the first place.

And if you're grouping by the same set of columns you're selecting, you can simply use

```
SELECT DISTINCT fname, lname
```

You could instead use `UNION DISTINCT` instead of `UNION ALL`, since you want duplicates to be removed. Then you don't need to do grouping or `DISTINCT` in the outer query.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to use `UNION DISTINCT`. It should be made clear that if you do this, it's unnecessary to do `GROUP BY` or `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it from "also" to "instead" and added more explanation.

Comment: @Barmar, I tested you proposed solution. It did improved the execution time (from 53 secs to 25 secs - based on PMA displayed time) but still took a long time. Is there any place for improvement?

Comment: Other search queries show different and sometimes much shorter execution time.

Comment: I've never really understood the point of using `TINYTEXT`, since you can just use `VARCHAR(255)` for the same thing, and you don't have to work around the limitations of the text types.

Comment: So doesn't it limit the FT index usage? Would it behave the same as `tinytext`?

Comment: As far as I know, FT indexes work the same on `TEXT` and `CHAR` columns. I don't see anything in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html that says you need to use text.